# Django Validation with and or rule

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-validation

The condition supposed to be only if this field is filled other field do not need to filled. Now with this code i have to fill out all the fields.

```
 if (self.start==None and self.end==None) or (self.running==None  and self.walking==None ) :
        raise ValidationError(
            {
                "start": _("Need to be filled"),
                 "end": _("Need to be filled"),
                "running": _("Need to be filled"),
                "walking": _("Need to be filled")
            }
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
if self.start==None and self.end==None and self.running==None and self.walking==None:
   raise ValidationError(
            {
                "start": _("Need to be filled"),
                "end": _("Need to be filled"),
                "running": _("Need to be filled"),
                "walking": _("Need to be filled")
            }
        )

if (self.start!=None or self.end!=None) and (self.running!=None or self.walking!=None):
   raise ValidationError(
            {
                "running": _("Don't need to be filled"),
                "walking": _("Don't need to be filled")
            }
        )

if self.start!=None and self.end==None:
   raise ValidationError(
            {
                "end": _("Need to be filled")
            }
        )

if self.start==None and self.end!=None:
   raise ValidationError(
            {
                "start": _("Need to be filled")
            }
        )

if self.running!=None and self.walking==None:
   raise ValidationError(
            {
                "walking": _("Need to be filled")
            }
        )

if self.running==None and self.walking!=None:
   raise ValidationError(
            {
                "running": _("Need to be filled")
            }
        )
```

Comment: sorry it is not working, it is asking all the filled to be filled

Comment: @Kane It should ask to fill one from start/end and one from running/walking, if it works different there is something that does not work before this code. Share all the code involved

Comment: I wish i have more tcode, i can give you the field, start = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, help_text=_("Start Machine"))

Comment: all  the other field have same model field

Comment: @Kane Do you perform this validation in in your model `save`/`clean `method?

Comment: yes  save/clean method,         def clean(self):

Comment: @Kane Is the problem you want to solve that the exception is raised even when it's not needed, or do you just want to change the exception message?

Comment: sorry if i understood wrong , yes when is needed i have to  raise validation error.

Comment: @Kane No problem, to let me understand, tell me if my new answer (I edited it) works as you intend

Comment: Sorry stilll not working

Comment: @Kane With "it is asking all the filled to be filled" what do you mean? Is about the message or about when the exception is raised?

Comment: i am giving this two screen shot link you will understand ,https://ibb.co/kM8Bfq1
,https://ibb.co/WgTCgCT

Comment: @Kane Ok it' s about the message, it you want only one from start/end to be filled, what message you want to appear if the two values are different from None?

Comment: Ok my jobe is to make sure if start and end will values then walking and eunning do not need to filled, also if  running and walking is filled wity value then do not value in start end

Comment: @Kane Ok maybe I have understand, try my new answer